# Improve performance of query to update only 1 column instead of 3

Tags: mysql, sql

As you can see from my query below, I am updating `percenting_pages` and `percentile_visits` columns for company 1.

```
UPDATE mytable 
SET    percentile_pages = CASE 
                            WHEN pages >= 1 
                                 AND pages < 2 THEN 25 
                            WHEN pages >= 2 
                                 AND pages < 3 THEN 35 
                            WHEN pages >= 3 
                                 AND pages < 5 THEN 40 
                            WHEN pages >= 5 THEN 45 
                            ELSE percentile_pages 
                          END, 
       percentile_visits = CASE 
                             WHEN visits >= 2 
                                  AND visits < 3 THEN 25 
                             WHEN visits >= 3 
                                  AND visits < 4 THEN 35 
                             WHEN visits >= 4 
                                  AND visits < 6 THEN 40 
                             WHEN visits >= 6 THEN 45 
                             ELSE percentile_visits 
                           END
WHERE  company = 1
```

After, in an extra these 2 columns (`percentile_visits` and `percentile_pages`) I will SUM this 2 columns in order to update the `total_percentile` column.

What I want to do, is to avoid updating `percentile_visits` and `percentile_pages` and instead update only 1 column, the `total_percentile`.

This of course will allow me to optimize my app. Is there any way to edit the query that instead of updating the columns, to sum each "value"?

Comment: Your setup stores information twice: the percentiles are implied in the page counts.That violates normal form and is usually a bad idea. Consider storing just the page counts, and calculating the percentiles when you need them.

Comment: Percentile_pages and percentile_visits may default to null - if so problems may arise if the else in the case statement ever occurs.

Answer (score 2):

You could add the values  this way

If you need  only the total_percentile and  for this your remove the columns `percentile_pages` and `percentile_visits` then you could change one of these column in else with `total_percentile`  and set 0 for the second

```
UPDATE mytable 
SET    
      total_percentile = (CASE 
                            WHEN pages >= 1 
                                 AND pages < 2 THEN 25 
                            WHEN pages >= 2 
                                 AND pages < 3 THEN 35 
                            WHEN pages >= 3 
                                 AND pages < 5 THEN 40 
                            WHEN pages >= 5 THEN 45 
                            ELSE total_percentile 
                          END) + 
                          ( CASE 
                             WHEN visits >= 2 
                                  AND visits < 3 THEN 25 
                             WHEN visits >= 3 
                                  AND visits < 4 THEN 35 
                             WHEN visits >= 4 
                                  AND visits < 6 THEN 40 
                             WHEN visits >= 6 THEN 45 
                             ELSE 0 
                           END) 
WHERE  company = 1
```

or if you need  update  all  the 3 columns

```
UPDATE mytable 
SET    percentile_pages = CASE 
                            WHEN pages >= 1 
                                 AND pages < 2 THEN 25 
                            WHEN pages >= 2 
                                 AND pages < 3 THEN 35 
                            WHEN pages >= 3 
                                 AND pages < 5 THEN 40 
                            WHEN pages >= 5 THEN 45 
                            ELSE percentile_pages 
                          END, 
       percentile_visits = CASE 
                             WHEN visits >= 2 
                                  AND visits < 3 THEN 25 
                             WHEN visits >= 3 
                                  AND visits < 4 THEN 35 
                             WHEN visits >= 4 
                                  AND visits < 6 THEN 40 
                             WHEN visits >= 6 THEN 45 
                             ELSE percentile_visits 
                           END, 
      total_percentile = (CASE 
                            WHEN pages >= 1 
                                 AND pages < 2 THEN 25 
                            WHEN pages >= 2 
                                 AND pages < 3 THEN 35 
                            WHEN pages >= 3 
                                 AND pages < 5 THEN 40 
                            WHEN pages >= 5 THEN 45 
                            ELSE percentile_pages 
                          END) + 
                          ( CASE 
                             WHEN visits >= 2 
                                  AND visits < 3 THEN 25 
                             WHEN visits >= 3 
                                  AND visits < 4 THEN 35 
                             WHEN visits >= 4 
                                  AND visits < 6 THEN 40 
                             WHEN visits >= 6 THEN 45 
                             ELSE percentile_visits 
                           END) 
WHERE  company = 1
```

Comment: Hi there, thank you for this. I am referring to your first example: Let's say since I will update only 1 column (total_percentile) i will remove from the table the other 2 columns since I don't need them anymore.  In that case, how do I change the first example? Do I just remove the `ELSE percentile_pages` and `ELSE percentile_visits` ?

Comment: @EnexoOnoma  answer  updated  avoding use of the columns you want remove

Answer (score 1):

You say that you want to update the **column**. So I assume that by "SUM" you don't mean the aggregate `SUM()` function but a plain sum, otherwise you would be updating a *row* value (maybe the one for company = ID_ALL?).

If my assumption is correct you can just say

```
UPDATE mytable 
SET    total_percentile = CASE ... ELSE 0 END + CASE ... ELSE 1 END
       WHERE (visits > 1 OR pages > 0) [ AND company = 1 ]
```

The two CASEs are the one you already use, except that the ELSE has been replaced by 0. This creates a border case when pages = 1 and visits = 0, but I expect that to be unlikely.

The query will work for a single company, or for any selection of them.

Answer (score 0):

Your "optimization" seems pretty meaningless.  Most of the time spent on an update involves logging and modifying the data, not setting individual columns.  Updating three columns in a row has exactly the same overhead as updating one column, because the whole row is a unit.

I can suggest a simplification of your code.  This isn't a performance optimization, just a simplification:

```
UPDATE mytable 
    SET percentile_pages = (CASE WHEN pages >= 5 THEN 45
                                 WHEN pages >= 3 THEN 40
                                 WHEN pages >= 2 THEN 35
                                 WHEN pages >= 1 THEN 25
                                 ELSE percentile_pages
                            END),
       percentile_visits = (CASE WHEN visits >= 6 THEN 45
                                 WHEN visits >= 4 THEN 40
                                 WHEN visits >= 3 THEN 35
                                 WHEN visits >= 2 THEN 25
                                 ELSE percentile_visits
                            END),
       total_percentile =  (CASE WHEN pages >= 5 THEN 45
                                 WHEN pages >= 3 THEN 40
                                 WHEN pages >= 2 THEN 35
                                 WHEN pages >= 1 THEN 25
                                 ELSE percentile_pages
                            END) +
                           (CASE WHEN visits >= 6 THEN 45
                                 WHEN visits >= 4 THEN 40
                                 WHEN visits >= 3 THEN 35
                                 WHEN visits >= 2 THEN 25
                                 ELSE percentile_visits
                            END)
    WHERE company = 1 AND (visits >= 2 OR pages >= 1);
```

One important reason why just updating the `total_percentile` will not do what you want is for the *next* update.  In the case the `visits` or `pages` doesn't change, you need the previous value of `percentile_pages` and `percentile_visits`.

In any case, there is no real performance gain from doing not updating the individual values.